# Turn off scientific notation MySQL

Tags: mysql

When I insert a `DOUBLE`, why do I see a value like `9.755046187483832e17` when I select that value? How can I retrieve a number like `975504618748383289` instead?

Comment: One big advantage of scientific notation is that it fairly represents the precision available in a value.  If the exponent were `30` (`1.23e30`), then fixed point notation would generate approximately 14 random digits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [`FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_format) or [`ROUND`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) function:

Using `FORMAT()`, depending on your *locale* and your specific needs, you might have to replace the *thousands-separator*:

```
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(9.755046187483832e17,0);
975,504,618,748,383,200

mysql> SELECT REPLACE(FORMAT(9.755046187483832e17,0), ',','');
975504618748383200
```

On the other hand, `ROUND()` being a *numeric* function, it only outputs *digits*:

```
mysql> SELECT ROUND(9.755046187483832e17,0);
975504618748383200
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/17614 for playing with that.

---

**EDIT:** As you noticed, the last two digits are rounded to *00*. That's because of [`DOUBLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/floating-point-types.html) precision limits. You have to remember that *double* are *approximate*. If you need precise values and/or more digits than available with the 16-bits precision of double, you probably needs to change your column's type to [`DECIMAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html). By default `DECIMAL` has 10 digits precision (10 *base 10* digits). You could explicitly request up to 65 digits.

For example, if you need up to 20 digits precision, you write something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (myValue DECIMAL(20), ...
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html

Please note however than things are *not* that simple. Selecting the decimal column might silently convert it to *double* (or *bigint* ?) thus loosing the extra precision. You might have to explicitly cast to string in order to preserve the full precision. That means the you might have to deal with that at application level.

```
create table tbl (dblValue DOUBLE, decValue DECIMAL(20,0));
insert into tbl values (975504618748383289, 975504618748383289);

SELECT dblValue, decValue FROM tbl;
--> DBLVALUE            DECVALUE
--> 975504618748383200  975504618748383200

SELECT CAST(dblValue AS CHAR), CAST(decValue AS CHAR) FROM tbl;
--> CAST(DBLVALUE AS CHAR)  CAST(DECVALUE AS CHAR)
--> 9.755046187483832e17    975504618748383289
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5f58/2 for examples.

Comment: Thanks, but that sets the last two digits to 0. I need the values of the tens and ones.

Comment: @RosePerrone There _is_ no value for the tens and ones. At least in Sylvain's example. You might get some other results, but keep in mind that [a double only has around 16 decimals digits of precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Comment: @RosePerrone I have largely edited my answer with respect to the loss of precision.

Answer (score 0):

The double has a precision of about 16 digits.  If you need more precision you have two options.

If the value is an integer, you can use `bigint` up to about 19 digits of precision.

Better is `decimal` which supports up to 65 digits.  For instance, the following returns an error:

```
select format(v*v*v*v*v*v*v*v, 0)
from (select 1001 as v) t
```

Because the value of `v` is treated as a `bigint`.

However, the following works very nicely:

```
select format(v*v*v*v*v*v*v*v, 0)
from (select cast(1001 as decimal(65, 0)) as v) t
```

Returning `1,008,028,056,070,056,028,008,001` -- which is the precise answer.

If you need precision up to 65 places, then use `decimal`.  Beyond that, you may have to write your own routines.  If you are not doing arithmetic on the field, then consider storing it as a string.