# SQL Query Returning Distorted Integer

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `player_data` (
    `id` BIGINT(225) DEFAULT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(225) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
    `gender` VARCHAR(225) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
    `model` VARCHAR(225) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
    `money` BIGINT(225) DEFAULT NULL,
    `playtime` BIGINT(225) DEFAULT NULL
```

);

I have a very simple query that is trying to fetch the `id`. Query:

```
SELECT id FROM player_data WHERE id = '"..id.."'
```

The ID in the table is 76561198342211128, however, when that query is run it returns 7.6561198342211e+16 is there any reason it's doing this based off what I've shown?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036091/turn-off-scientific-notation-mysql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turn off scientific notation MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036091/turn-off-scientific-notation-mysql)